# Combining identical columns, concatenating the column names in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix for a minimal example:

```
data <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
Matrix = matrix(data, nrow = 3, ncol=4)
colnames(Matrix) <-c("4","3","7","100")
rownames(Matrix) <-c("bob","foo","bar")
> Matrix
    4 3 7 100
bob 1 1 2   3
foo 1 1 2   4
bar 1 1 3   4
```

I want to combine any identical columns, besides the names, and update the colnames such that I know the original columns that were identical I have tried using loops to find the duplicates, but I can't get the combining names part.

The expected result would be something like the following matrix:

```
>Matrix 
    4-3   7   100
bob   1   2    3
foo   1   2    4
bar   1   3    4
```

Comment: I think your example is not correct `as.matrix` would be `matrix`?

Comment: If I change to `matrix`, the first column is `1 1 1` and second is `1 2 2`. it is not identical.  Did you meant `data <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)`

Comment: yes, thank you my real data is much bigger and I generally don't make matrices that often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another base R option

```
do.call(
    cbind,
    Map(
        function(x) `colnames<-`(Matrix[, (nm<-names(x))[1], drop = FALSE], paste0(nm, collapse = "-")),
        split(u <-unlist(Map(toString, as.data.frame(Matrix))), u)
    )
)
```

which gives

```
    4-3 7 100
bob   1 2   3
foo   1 2   4
bar   1 3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

We could `split` the columns into a `list` based on the `paste`d values of the column, then get the first column, `paste` the column names and `cbind`

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(unname(split.default(as.data.frame(Matrix),
     apply(Matrix, 2, paste, collapse = ''))), 
   function(x) matrix(x[,1], 
      dimnames = list(NULL, paste(colnames(x), collapse='-')))))
```

Comment: The only thing with this is you need to replace the rownames after this step